# click for specific element inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, click

my web app contains some dragable elements that would be inserted into a div , i want to listen on user click to this element inserted into the div

what i want is jquery function that capture the click and if the element clicked is wihtin the div do something

the element has a class removable

```
 <button class="month draggable removable btn" id="01" month="01">Janvier</button>
```

this the div to whitch the element will be dragged

```
<div   class="execute droppable" style="width: 800px;height: 200px;margin-left:10%;margin-top: 3%;border-style: dashed;border:0.5" >
        </div>
```

Comment: I recommend that you reword your post to ask a specific question rather than a general "what I want is". At the moment, your post isn't really a question at all, and we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [jQuery `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler:

```
$("div.execute").on("click", ".removable", function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
});
```